# Acessar imagem do resources spring

Tags: java, imagem, spring

tenho o seguinte cenário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Tenho o arquivo srping-servlet.xml com a seguinte configuração:

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="com.websystique.springmvc.controller" />

 <mvc:annotation-driven />
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

 
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix">
   <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
  </property>
  <property name="suffix">
   <value>.jsp</value>
  </property>
 </bean>

</beans>
```

Tenho o metodo Hello World que quero mostrar a imagem por exemplo logo_vallon.jpg e estou usando o seguinte codigo na classe HelloWorldController.java:

```html
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String sayHello(ModelMap model) {
  model.addAttribute("greeting", "<img src=\"/resources/images/logo_vallon.jpg\"/>Hello World from Spring 4 MVC");
  return "welcome";
 }
```

porem quando mando rodar o codigo fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

quando mando mostrar as informações da pagina fica assim:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>HelloWorld page</title>
</head>
<body>
 Greeting : <img src="/resources/images/logo_vallon.jpg"/>Hello World from Spring 4 MVC
</body>
</html>
```

e o arquivo jsp está sendo criado dessa forma:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>HelloWorld page</title>
</head>
<body>
 Greeting : ${greeting}
</body>
</html>
```

Já estou a mais de 3 dias tentando fazer a imagem aparecer sem sucesso, alguem pode me dar uma luz para isso por favor? pode me dizer onde está o erro?

Answer (score 1):

Depois de muitas horas, segue a resposta:

```
<img src="images/logo_vallon.jpg"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/WEB-INF/images/" />
```